# Installing Android SDK using HomeBrew

Tags: android

I am trying to install react native on Mac, Below is the link of the tutorial I am following to install:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLgJreGpfyM

I need to install android-sdk using homebrew. But i get the below error:

```
Harshithas-MacBook-Air:~ harsh$ brew cask install android-sdk
==> Caveats
We will install android-sdk-tools, platform-tools, and build-tools for you.
You can control android sdk packages via the sdkmanager command.
You may want to add to your profile:
  'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk'

This operation may take up to 10 minutes depending on your internet connection.
Please, be patient.

==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-3859397.zip
Already downloaded: /Users/harsh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/android-sdk--3859397.zip
==> Verifying checksum for Cask android-sdk
==> Installing Cask android-sdk
==> Warning: File /Users/harsh/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
==> Warning: Failed to find package build-tools;26.0.0
Error: Command failed to execute!

==> Failed command:
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools build-tools;26.0.0

==> Standard Output of failed command:


==> Standard Error of failed command:
Warning: File /Users/harsh/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Warning: Failed to find package build-tools;26.0.0


==> Exit status of failed command:
#<Process::Status: pid 85707 exit 1>
Error: Install incomplete.
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks,
Harshitha Ramesh

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/Users/harsh/.android` directory before installing `android-sdk`?